# Terminal screen will not be refreshed after suspending program: is this a bug or a default configuration problem?

Tags: command-line, gnome, gnome-terminal, emacs

Sometimes after suspending emacs(CTRL+Z) terminal screen refreshes incorrectly:

[image]

Never experienced this problem in Ubuntu 12.04 (my current version is 14.04 with gnome-shell 3.6.2)